Typesetting my poems
I am facing issues with typesetting my poem that I intend to be a visual poem. I want to arrange it into two major chunks,one chunk of the text representing the dot of i and the other, body of i. No issues with stanza or line breaks,it's gonna be a chunk.And the i should be in italics. (Pl refer the img)
Could someone guide me how to type the poem in the above said format

Hi, welcome to TeX StackExchange! Is this similar to what you want to achieve?
